Swap tokens on Uniswap v3 with Python code. Error - insufficient funds for gas * price + value
I try to use the following code to exchange tokens on the Uniswap V3 exchanger in the Arbitrum network.
from web3 import Account, Web3
from abi import UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER2_ABI, WETH9_ABI, MIN_ERC20_ABI

private_key = "pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp"  # 1 где есть арбитрум

chain_id = 42161
rpc_endpoint = "https://arb1.arbitrum.io/rpc"

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc_endpoint))
account = Account.from_key(private_key)

total_gas_used_buy = 0
amount_in = 0.0000000004

weth_address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x35751007a407ca6feffe80b3cb397736d2cf4dbe")
usdc_address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xaf88d065e77c8cc2239327c5edb3a432268e5831")
swap_router02_address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45")

# load contracts
swap_router_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=swap_router02_address, abi=UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER2_ABI)
weth_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=weth_address, abi=WETH9_ABI)
usdc_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=usdc_address, abi=MIN_ERC20_ABI)

# wrap eth
tx = weth_contract.functions.deposit().build_transaction({
        'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
        'gas': 200000,
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas": web3.eth.max_priority_fee,
        "maxFeePerGas": 100 * 10**9,
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address),
        'value': int(web3.to_wei(amount_in, 'ether')) # wrap eth
})

signed_transaction = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key)
tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)

tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
print(f"tx hash: {Web3.to_hex(tx_hash)}")

When starting, an error appears about insufficient funds for gas.
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x1111111111111111111 have 4014074730000000 want 20000000400000000'}

The error shows my ETH balance which is 0.004 - $15 dollars. On the Arbitrum network commissions are small but it turns out that this swap requires a commission much more than $15.
I tried to reduce 'gas': 200000, to 200, but then the error is thrown: "ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'intrinsic gas too low'}."
I am looking forward to the opportunity to make swaps with the minimum commission inherent in the Arbitrum network.

put 1500000 in and you should be fine. Or you can check the document of ARB to check the gas. https://docs.arbitrum.io/build-decentralized-apps/precompiles/reference#arbgasinfo

Thanks, it worked! I changed "maxFeePerGas": 100 * 10**9 to "maxFeePerGas": 15000000.
